# Insert into remote Couchbase server by Python

Tags: python, couchbase

I use this code to insert data into Couchbase

```
from couchbase import Couchbase

c = Couchbase.connect(host="remote-server.com", bucket="default")
c.set('first_key', 'first-_value')
```

But I got this error:

```
couchbase.exceptions.TimeoutError: <Key=u'first_key', RC=0x17[Operation timed out], Operational Error, Results=1, C Source=(src/multiresult.c,148)>
```

And, I tried these steps:

1. I printed c (Couchbase connection object) out

   The object was created so it connected to Couchbase server
   successfully?
2. I tried to telnet remote-server.com at port 8091, it
   connected successfully, too.
3. Increase timeout connection to 30
   seconds.

But, the problem has not been solved.

Answer (score 2):

To connect to couchbase you should ensure that your server is configured with dns name `remote-server.com`, not `IP`, not `localhost`. And couchbase server also should be able to get ip via this dns name.

I.e. if you host your server in AWS EC2, couchbase usally get internal IP address like 10.X.X.X and even if you try to access it from internet via public ip with clien library, your request will be timed out. But you will be able to access REST API, and admin console via public dns.

Also you should check all ports (not only 8091) needed by couchbase. See this [doc](http://www.couchbase.com/docs//couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-network-ports.html) for all ports needed to be opened.

Comment: I will check it tomorrow! Thank you!

Comment: Hi m03geek, I followed you instructions but it could not help. Error "Operation timed out" kept raising. If I try to use Administrator account to connect, I received this error "Administrator account must not be used to access the data in the bucket"

Comment: Ok. Can you provide some info about your couchbase server: 1) what IP (or hostname) do you see in Admin Console; 2) is that ip/hostname exactly same with ip/hostname in your app (in Couchbase.connect function); 3) can you connect via telnet to other couchbase ports like 8092, 11211; 4) does couchbase server correctly resolve ip by hostname (if it was configured to use hostname)?